# Python, Selenium: can't find element by xpath when ul list is too long

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to create a program extracting all persons I follow on Instagram. I'm using Python, Selenium and Chromedriver.

To do so, I first get the number of followed persons and click on the 'following' button : `

```
nb_abonnements = int(webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/span[1]/section[1]/main/div[1]/header/section[1]/ul/li[3]/a/span').text)

sleep(randrange(1,3))
abonnements = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/span[1]/section[1]/main/div[1]/header/section[1]/ul/li[3]/a')
abonnements.click()
```

I then use the following code to get the followers and scroll the popup page in case I can't find one:

```
followers_panel = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]')
while i < nb_abonnements:
    try:
        print(i)
        followed = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/ul/div/li[{}]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/a'.format(i+1)).text
        #the followeds are in an ul-list
        i += 1
        followed_list.append(followed)
        except NoSuchElementException:
        webdriver.execute_script(
            "arguments[0].scrollBy(0,400)",followers_panel
        )
        sleep(7)
```

The problem is once i is at 12, the program raises the exception and scrolls. From there, he still can't find the next follower and is stuck in a loop where he does nothing but scroll. I've checked the source codeof the IG page, and it turns out the path is still good, but apparently I can't access the elements as I do anymore, probably because the ul-list in which I am accessing them has become to long (line 5 of the program).

I can't work out how to solve this. I hope you will be of some help.

UPDATE: the DOM looks like this:

```
html
    body
        span
        script
        ...
        div[3]
              div
                 ...
                     div
                         div
                         div[2]
                               ul
                                 div
                                    li
                                    li
                                    li
                                    li
                                    ...
                                    li
```

The `ul` is the list of the followers.
The `li`s contain the info i'm trying to extract (username). Even when I go go by myself on the webpage, open the popup window, scroll a little and let everything load, I can't find the element I'm looking for by typing the xpath in the search bar of the DOM manually. Although the path is correct, I can check it by looking at the DOM.

I've tried various webdrivers for selenium, currently I am using chromedriver 2.45.615291. I've also put an explicit wait to wait for the element to show (`WebDriverWait(webdriver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/ul/div/li[{}]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/a'.format(i+1))))`), but I just get a timeout exception: `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`.

It just seems like once the ul list is too long (which is from the moment I've scrolled down enough to load new people), I can't access any element of the list by its XPATH, even the elements that were already loaded before I began scrolling.

Comment: Have you tried waiting for element's visibility/existence?

Comment: That can't be it. Even when I'm doing it by hand, I can't access the element by typing the xpath manually. Although I check via the source code that the path is indeed correct, searching with a ctrl+F just says it doesn't exist.

Comment: can u show us the DOM

Comment: i've updated my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've foud a solution: i just access the element through the XPATH like this: `find_element_by_xpath("(//*[@class='FPmhX notranslate _0imsa '])[{}]".format(i))`. I don't know why it didn't work the other way, but like this it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using xpath for each of the child element... find the ul-list element then find all the child elements using something like : ul-list element.find_elements_by_tag_name(). Then iterate through each element in the collection & get the required text

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I've found a way aroud my problem, which I've posted below.